# Mismatching interpolations

Tags: opengl, interpolation, vulkan

Look at this two images:

[image]
[image]

Red and blue channels are zero on both pictures, while the green channel is the x coordinate of that point. The x coordinate is in range (-1, 1).

The first image was calculated on the CPU:

```
double screenHeight = 750;
double screenWidth = 750;
double viewportWidth = 2.0;

for (int i = 0; i < screenHeight; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < screenWidth; ++j) {
        float greenChannel = (double)j / screenWidth * viewportWidth;
    }
}
```

The second one was calculated on the GPU:
First, vertex shader was told to draw three vertices (but none were given, more info [here](https://www.saschawillems.de/blog/2016/08/13/vulkan-tutorial-on-rendering-a-fullscreen-quad-without-buffers/)):

```
layout (location = 0) out vec2 outUV;

void main() {
    outUV = vec2((gl_VertexIndex << 1) & 2, gl_VertexIndex & 2);
    gl_Position = vec4(vec2(outUV) * 2.0f + -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

This essentially sent the baricentric coordinates to each of the fragments. They were interpolated between the three values. Fragment shader then did the following calculations:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec2 outUV;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    double viewportWidth = 2.0;
    double c = (outUv.x - 0.5) * viewportWidth;
    outColor = vec4(vec3(0.0, float(c), 0.0), 1.0);
}
```

This first moves the x coordinate so that it's now in the range (-0.5, -0.5) and then scales it to get it to (-1, 1) range.

If you look at the images again, you'll notice that they aren't the same. The CPU one is much smoother near the center, while the one rendered on the GPU has a more abrupt transition. Do you have any idea what might cause that? It looks like it might be due to loss of precision somewhere on the GPU. I thought that the interpolated floats weren't precise enough, so I tried a different approach for c:

```
double screenWidth = 750;
double viewportWidth = 2.0;
double c = (gl_FragCoord.xy - 0.5 * screenWidth )/ screenWidth  * viewportWidth;
```

This uses gl_FragCoord and the resolution of the screen instead of relying on the interpolated value. It gave me results that were indistinguishable from the first attempt, so I guess it's not the interpolation. Just to be sure, I calculated c the both ways and compared them. They were exactly the same up to the 7th decimal.

Does anyone have any idea why the two images aren't the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GPU image is the correct one -- seems like you have sRGB handling enabled (which is good!). Consequently your GPU code interpolates in linear and then applies the sRGB gamma compression function. In OpenGL this behavior is controlled by `glEnable/Disable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)`. In Vulkan it's [configured when creating the swapchain](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Presentation/Swap_chain).

Your CPU code interpolates in the 'wrong' colorspace -- i.e. by calculating directly in the sRGB values as-if they were linear, even though they are not.

You can fix your CPU code as follows:

```
float greenChannel = ...;
greenChannel = greenChannel <= 0.0031308f ? 12.92f*greenChannel : 1.055f*powf(greenChannel, 1/2.4f) - 0.055f;
```

Comment: I actually want the colors to be drawn linearly, so I changed the code to use `vk::ColorSpaceKHR::ePassThroughEXT`, which now produces the same results as the CPU variant. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I was confused at first, so let me clarify the answer a little bit. The values I calculate in all examples are exactly the same (ignoring real number representation limits). What is different is how those values are mapped to actual colours.

Comment: @Karlovsky120: You got it backwards. The GPU was drawing them linearly, the CPU wasn't.

Comment: If you want perceptual uniformity you are better to use something off completely, like CIELUV or CIELAB.

Comment: Oh. Well, it's all the same to me, I just needed to confirm that the numbers were the same. However, knowing this will probably save me a headache or two in the future. Thanks for taking the extra time to clarify it.